# Running react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner in react native, from visual studio code I launched the npm start command which worked well, I want to run the application on an emulator, I followed a tutorial which had a web page in localhost:19000 which I didn’t get, I need to see this page to start running on the emulator.
thank you for helping me.

what i got when i typed localhost:19000

{“name”:“FirstApp”,“slug”:“FirstApp”,“version”:“1.0.0”,“orientation”:“portrait”,“icon”:“./assets/icon.png”,“userInterfaceStyle”:“light”,“splash”:{“image”:“./assets/splash.png”,“resizeMode”:“contain”,“backgroundColor”:“#ffffff”,“imageUrl”:“http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/splash.png"},“updates”:{“fallbackToCacheTimeout”:0},“assetBundlePatterns”:[“**/*”],“ios”:{“supportsTablet”:true},“android”:{“adaptiveIcon”:{“foregroundImage”:“./assets/adaptive-icon.png”,“backgroundColor”:“#FFFFFF”,“foregroundImageUrl”:“http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/adaptive-icon.png”}},“web”:{“favicon”:“./assets/favicon.png”},“_internal”:{“isDebug”:false,“projectRoot”:“C:\Users\imane\FirstApp”,“dynamicConfigPath”:null,“staticConfigPath”:“C:\Users\imane\FirstApp\app.json”,“packageJsonPath”:“C:\Users\imane\FirstApp\package.json”},“sdkVersion”:“46.0.0”,“platforms”:[“ios”,“android”],“iconUrl”:“http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/icon.png”,“debuggerHost”:“127.0.0.1:19000”,“logUrl”:“http://127.0.0.1:19000/logs”,“developer”:{“tool”:“expo-cli”,“projectRoot”:“C:\Users\imane\FirstApp”},“packagerOpts”:{“dev”:true},“mainModuleName”:“node_modules\expo\AppEntry”,“__flipperHack”:"React Native packager is running”,“hostUri”:“127.0.0.1:19000”,“bundleUrl”:“http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules\expo\AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false",“id”:"@anonymous/FirstApp-3d9589aa-1c21-436a-aae9-663bfebc30de”}

what I tried

[image]

what i expected to happen

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The web Ui has been removed from expo:

[Blog article from Expo](https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206)

You can't use this anymore.
To launch your app, you can scan the qrcode from the expo go app available on both android and iOS.
You might need to login on iOS on both cli and mobile app to see your app.

To launch on an emulator, you can press the `i` key in the terminal.
You can also hit the `?`key to see a list of available commands.